# Proper admin panel implementation in angular

Tags: angular

I just finished the front-end part of an application I am creating using angular 4. I am now in the process of creating an admin panel that will have a separate login page and two or three components. At first I created **a new module** and used the router to create some **"/admin"** routes. The problem is that the app component has the **header which I do not need**. Using *ngIf to check the current URL seems too much ghetto way for that. Is it better to simple **create a second angular application** for the admin pages? What's the best approach?

Comment: this depends on your needs and preferences

Comment: I want the application to be scalable and will grow way too big to tolerate such navbar ngIf statements. In my view I should create a second front-end application for the admins but I would like to know if this is some kind of anti-pattern.

Comment: no, it is even quite a good option. You can even make two applications that share the same code and the same project. Do you use angular-cli?

Comment: Yes I do use the angular-CLI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is quite broad but I'll try to cover the case with multiple apps.

Advantages of having multiple apps:

- the admin app is usually heavy and user's app is usually very optimised. So splitting the code into two apps is really helpful: the client is just not loading admin modules
- you are able to run only admin or only client app - this is really saving time when the project gets heavy enough
- the shared modules can get different global configurations because they are bootstrapped in different apps. So this is more flexible

Downsides:

- the initial configuration step requires some knowledge and time investment

For angular-cli you can use the following approach. Create two applications in the .angular-cli.json (see the [json schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)). You should have something like

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "..."
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "ci/dist-default",
      "assets": [...],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main-default.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [...],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "admin",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "ci/dist-admin",
      "assets": [...],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main-admin.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [...],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Create your `app-admin.module.ts` and `app-admin.component.ts` for the admin panel which is mostly copy-pasting your original modules. Then you need to create another `main-admin.ts` file which will import the `app-admin.module.ts`.

Ideally would be good to have two separate folders for app1 and app2.

That's it! Now you have two applications that can use the same codebase within one project.

Then it's time to adapt your `package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-admin": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json --app=admin --base-href=/admin/ --port=4201",
    "start-default": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json --app=default",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others 'npm run start-default' 'npm run start-admin'",
    "build-admin": "ng build --app=admin --base-href=/admin/",
    "build-default": "ng build --app=default",
    "build": "concurrently 'npm run build-default' 'npm run build-admin'",
    "build-prod": "concurrently 'npm run build-default -- -prod' 'npm run build-admin -- -prod'"
  },
```

Some explanation:

- app parameter uses the app name to build
- base-href is used to locate the admin project under `/admin` path, see [base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). This is required because after the build you will have two different apps and they cannot be both served by the same path
- we have two ports: 4200 and 4201 to run the apps simultaneously and use a proxy to serve `/admin/` part from 4200 if you run both apps together

See proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/admin": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4201",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/admin": ""
    }
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

In the end you have something like this

[image].

This requires some tricks and understanding of proxies. Also you would need to configure your live server with the same proxy settings for /admin path. However it really worth it, I use it for quite some time and cannot call it a bad solution

Comment: The CLI is a lot more powerful than I thought. Indeed there are two main approaches and this is a broad question but I believe you and A.Tim gave a very good answer. For this project I will follow your approach since this is what I was trying to do from the beginning but failing to understand the difference of module vs app.

Comment: Both are just abstractions, however the app can be deployed separately and module is just a building block. App in some sense is a configuration of set of modules. So when working with apps you are just managing the modules to be standalone. This is also good to have different configuration on modules.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. Could help someone coming from google one day.

Comment: May you clear your answer so that I can manage it. Should I create 2 separate modules inside an Angular project? or I have to do it manually, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Actually, I want to do it in Angular 6. so kindly explain it briefly or create a blog for the same. I much need it. Please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 2):

Just move `application-nav-header` into separate component.

- application.component.html

`` <alert-component></alert-component> <!-- Place there what is shared between `public` and `admin` -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet> ``

- public.component.html

`<public-nav-header-component></public-nav-header-component> <!-- NavHeader that customers can see -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

- admin.component.html

`<admin-nav-header-component></admin-nav-header-component> <!-- AdminNavHeader -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

- application.routes.ts

`[
    {path: "/", component: PublicComponent},
    {path: "/admin", component: AdminComponent}
]`

- admin.routes.ts

`[
    {path: "/login", component: LoginComponent},
    {path: "/user-listing", component: UserListingComponent}
]`

- public.routes.ts - move your current `application.routes` here

Comment: Very nice description of solving the problem without creating a second application. Thanks. I still might create a second application if I see that the project is getting bigger.